# Angular - SpringBoot - CORS (unknown url): 0 Unknown Error

Tags: angular, spring-boot, cors

I have a pretty simple Angular 6 service that calls a Spring Boot service.
Here is how it looks like in Angular :

```
getData(user, numberOfRequests, graphDepth, max): Observable<String> {
    var headers = new Headers();
    var body = {    "user" : user,
                    "numberofRequests" : numberOfRequests,
                    "graphDepth" : graphDepth,
                    "max" : max };
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');    
    return this.http.post<String>('http://XX.XX.XXX.XXX:8083/collect', body, httpOptions);
}
```

Here is the server side :

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*")
    @RequestMapping(value = "/collect", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "application/json; charset=UTF-8")
    @ResponseBody
    public String startServices(@RequestBody UserParameters parameters) {
        LOGGER.info("Calling for data");
        String jsonOutput = collect.getData(parameters);
        LOGGER.info("Data ready to be served");
        return jsonOutput;
    }
```

It works well when both application run locally or when they run on 2 different VMs. But when I deploy on a cloud service I get something that seems to be a CORS error :

```
 Reason: CORS request did not succeed

error: error { target: XMLHttpRequest, isTrusted: true, lengthComputable: false, … }
headers: Object { normalizedNames: Map(0), lazyUpdate: null, headers: Map(0) }
 message: "Http failure response for (unknown url): 0 Unknown Error"
 name: "HttpErrorResponse"
 ok: false
 status: 0
 statusText: "Unknown Error"
 url: null
```

This error happens when the webapp and the backend run on the same VM or in two separate VM with 2 different IP...

Do you know what could cause that problem ?
How can it be a CORS error ?
And do you know how can I try to fix it ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
httpOptions = {
    headers : new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'})
};

return this.http.post<String>('http://XX.XX.XXX.XXX:8083/collect', body, httpOptions);
```

How do you link the headers to the httpOptions?

For me that works.

Comment: Actually I had this on my class :  `const httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type':  'application/json',
      'Authorization': 'my-auth-token'
    })
  };`
Your modification bring the same issue...

Comment: Oh ok. You could also try some more changes:

In the Security configuration class (extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter), in the method configure(HttSecurity httpSecurity) try this:

http.cors().disable(); maybe even http.csrf().disable();

I hope this helps